# htaccess Rewriterule on URI with exceptions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite the following URLs:

http://www.web.de/productCat1 -> pass Var productCat1 to productCat.php
http://www.web.de/productCat1/product20 -> pass Var productCat1 + Var product20 to products.php
http://www.web.de/shop -> do nothing as file exists
http://www.web.de/contact -> do nothing as file exists

So far I have this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  

# PHP to NO Extension  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php

#catch all products
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+/[^/]+)/{0,1}$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/{0,1}$ /products.php?rw=1&url=$1/$2 [L,QSA]

#catch all categories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(shop|contact)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /productCat.php?rw=1&url=$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

After several attempts I'm still getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  

# PHP to NO Extension  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php

#catch all products
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ /products.php?rw=1&url=$1 [L,QSA]

# catch all categories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? /productCat.php?rw=1&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: My files on the Server were named differently, now with products.php and productCat.php it works all fine Thank you.